# Node.js - Functions from another file as parameter in a route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, routes

I'm trying to make my program a bit more modular because it's quite a mess now. But for every attempt at refactoring my code I always get a bunch of errors and a program that doesn't work.

What I want to do is create multiple files that have their own workload and if I need something of it in another file, I can basically "borrow" that function.

Example from my existing code :

Index.js

```
//Routers 
const getPostsRouter = require('./routes/getPosts');
app.use('/getPosts', getPostsRouter);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const authenticateToken = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
    if (token == null) return res.sendStatus(401);

    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
        req.user = user
        next()
    })
}

module.exports = authenticateToken;
```

Then in my getPosts.js file I want to be able to do something like

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../databaseConnection');
const {authenticateToken} = require('../index')

router.get('/', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
        await db.query('SELECT * FROM posts', 
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({errorMessage: err});
            }
            res.send(result);
        });
    }
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

But I always get this error when I try this : "Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]" which points to the line "const getPostsRouter = require('./routes/getPosts');" in index.js

EDIT:
The problem lied in circular dependencies! All I needed to do was erase one side of the dependency and now everything works as intended!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the brackets, because you're always exporting authenticateToken by defualt...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../databaseConnection');
const authenticateToken = require('../index'); // <---- HERE

router.get('/', authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
        await db.query('SELECT * FROM posts', 
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send({errorMessage: err});
            }
            res.send(result);
        });
    }
}); 

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I have tried that as well but then I get an error that says "Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object]", same line as before in index.js

Comment: @Kevin.J Are you exporting the router at the end of file ?

Comment: I had forgotten to include that in my post, I will edit it. But yes I am exporting the router at the end of the file, see my edit.

Comment: I think you should add the next parameter to the function you pass to the in `router.get` so instead of `async (req,res)` to `async (req,res, next)` also make the authenticateToken async

Comment: I tried applying your changes but I still get the same error.